# Float left not working correctly in Drupal form

Tags: php, html, css, drupal

I had been tasked to create a layout from a PSD file. I did that and here is the way the layout came out:

[image]

However, I then was asked to merge the HTML into the PHP for a Drupal site. It isn't quite working. You can see the site here:

[Drupal site](http://dev.redhatsociety.com/fact/locator/90630)

You can see that the two columns at the bottom don't work and the form fields don't line up correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few things wrong with your css that are causing things to mis-align..
your main issue is how you are using `float`, mainly as you're attempting to place floated block elements inline with non-block elements of text (you could similarly wrap your text in a `<p>` or `<div>` and give that a `float` style too)

ill do my best to list them here:
file: style_fact.css

line:174

```
.results-header{
    margin:0 auto; /* currently set to margin-left: 248px; */
}
```

line:323, 332, 337

```
div#edit-newzip-wrapper, div#edit-dist-wrapper, #edit-search{
    display:inline; /* currently set to float:left; */
    /* remove margin-top:1.5em; for #edit-search */
}
```

this results in something pretty close to your design

Comment: By adding your changes and display:inline to two other spots, I was able to make it work and come very close to my design. Thanks @haxxton!